# Use checkboxes to display objects with certain tags (jquery)

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a bunch of checkboxes on my site that all have unique ids. I want to use jquery to display html objects that have tags that match these ids. So if the user clicks "peaceful" it will display all the html objects that have "peaceful" as a tag. (i've added the tags manually in the html) Hopefully this makes sense. Here is the html code for the check boxes:

```
<div class="col-md-6 center checks" id="mood">
 <input type="checkbox" id="contemplative" > <span class="check">Contemplative</span>
 <input type="checkbox" id="peaceful">  <span class="check">Peaceful</span>
 <input type="checkbox"  id="aggresive"> <span class="check">Aggressive</span>
 <input type="checkbox"  id="heartbreak">  <span class="check">Heartbreak</span><br>
 <input type="checkbox" id="dark">  <span class="check">Dark</span> 
 <input type="checkbox"  id="epic">  <span class="check">Epic</span>
 <input type="checkbox" id="cheerful">  <span class="check">Cheerful</span>
 <input type="checkbox"  id="fun">  <span class="check">Fun</span><br>
 <input type="checkbox" id="atmospheric"> <span class="check">Atmospheric</span>
 <input type="checkbox"  id="upbeat">  <span class="check">Upbeat</span>
 <input type="checkbox" id="heartful">  <span class="check">Heartfelt</span> 
 <input type="checkbox" id="sad">  <span class="check">Sad</span> <br>
</div>
```

Sorry for not giving enough information! The objects are created with this script:

```
for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    console.log('index', i)
    el = '';
    var url = urls[i]
    console.log('item', url)
    // if (!url) continue
    el += '<li style="display: none;" data-tags="' + url.tags + '">'
    el += '<iframe width="550" height="100" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="' + url.src + '"></iframe>'
    el += '</li>'
    content += el
}
```

the tags and src are pulled from this array: (there are more items but I shortened for this)

```
var urls = [

 {
    tags: 'tv, film, score, instrumental, dark, mysterious, quirky, jon licht, Jon Licht, licht, Licht',
    src: "https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/365566355&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true"
 },
 {
    tags: 'tv, film, score, instrumental, dark, mysterious, quirky, jon licht, Jon Licht, licht, Licht',
    src: "https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/365565899&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true"
 },
```

]

Right now I have a search function that does something similar. I am looking to add the checkboxes as well. Here is the code for the search function:

```
var $input = $('#myInput');
$input.on('keyup', search)
function myFunction(e) {
    // Declare variables
    var $q, $el, tags, match, tags;


    $q = e.target.value
    var $list = $container.children('li')
    if ($q.length < 2) {
        $list.hide();
        return;
    }

    console.log('list', $list)
    queryTags = $q.split(',').map(tag => tag.trim())
    console.log('tags', tags)
    $list.each(function(index, el) {            
        $el = $(el)
        tags = $el.attr('data-tags')

        for (var j = 0; j < queryTags.length; j++) {    
            match = tags.match(queryTags[j])            
             if (queryTags.every(queryTag => tags.includes(queryTag))) 
             $el.show();
             else $el.hide();



        }
    })


    //do something
}
```

I hope this clears things up.

Comment: What do all these tags look like? And what have you tried? What is the specific problem accomplishing your goal?

Comment: where are the 'objects' you stated ? Did you try to code yourself ? I don't see any `JavaScript` code.

Comment: could you explain your 'peaceful' tag how did you add tag. I am assuming you did something like this `<span data-tag='peaceful'></span>` is this right?

Comment: My apologies on not giving enough information. Here are the objects that I want to be displayed when the checkboxes are checked.

Comment: @charlietfl I just added more information up top!

Comment: @ths just added more info up top!

Comment: @MunkhdelgerTumenbayar just added more info up top!

Comment: So what is or isn't working in code shown? A runnable demo would be helpful also. I think your problem is that data-tags is string not array and your query seems to treat as array and should definitely be array

Comment: @charlietfl the problem is I just can't seem to figure out how to create the code that will do what the search bar does but for the check boxes. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Please try below code if it helps

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {               
            var clickedBoxId = $(this).attr('id');
            $('['+clickedBoxId+']').each(function () {
                $(this).show();
                // Rest code you can do here

            });               
        });
    });
```

Comment: This worked to add the id to the variable clickedBoxID. Now I need to figure out a way to say IF clickedBoxID = a tag in one of the items of array [urls] then display this item. (You can see above I added some more information) thanks!

Comment: I can see that tags are same in both the objects (in the url array), will it be fixed for all the elements in the array.